# What exactly does bootstrapping in the caret R package do?

Tags: r, bootstrap

The documentation of the resampling method "boot" of `trainControl` only states that it does "the usual bootstrap". What exactly is that? Every publication I can find seems to define something different as "the usual bootstrap". For instance, the [rms package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/rms.pdf) cites eq. (2.10) in [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1983.10477973) for "ordinary bootstrapping" (which they call "boot") - which seems to be an optimism corrected bootstrapping method? Other versions of "standard bootstrapping" I've seen include bootstrapping without any optimism correction, validating a) on the whole dataset, or b) on the out-of-bag samples.

I tried to find the answer to my question in the code (it should be in [workflows.R](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/0579b5dded32f5af9c4c6f4ef5a3898d3839c4d0/pkg/caret/R/workflows.R)), but I'm having a hard time following what's going on, to be honest.

(This is a duplicate of [my identical question on the package's github page](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/1261), which has not received any answers in the past 11 days.)